# How to shorten a url that contained "#" symbol by TinyURL api?

Tags: php, api, webapi, short-url, tinyurl

For example, I want to shorten this url: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

I tried to pass `https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor` as url parameter, but the returned url is actually shorten from https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html, so it won't jump to *popen-constructor* section.

Then I tried to pass `https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html%23popen-constructor` as url parameter, but the returned url doesn't work (404 not found).

The only solution is to use website of TinyURL it self, so I'm wondering if I can shorten a url that contained a "#" symbol by TinyURL api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: due to stackoverflow security rules I can't add the tiny url. So in every examples bellow I have replace `https://tinyurl.com` by `https://<tinyurl>.com`*

You should encode whole target url, ie:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fsubprocess.html%23popen-constructor
```

Then, if you use api with the fully encode target url it will create a correct short link:

```
https://<tinyurl>.com/api-create.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fsubprocess.html%23popen-constructor
```

[image: result]

Tinyurl created (`https://<tinyurl>.com/q3anmqb`) will redirect to https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: Hi @PenutChen, if it fix the issue, please mark the question as answered. Thank you.